# How many orthogonal projectors on a given subspace are there?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

This question is probably trivial, for that I apologize.

Let's take a vector space $V$ equipped with a scalar product and a vector subspace $S\subset V$.

> How many different projectors onto S, orthogonal with respect to the scalar product, can be constructed? 
>   And what if $V$ is, more generally, a Hilbert space and $S$ is a finite-dimensional subspace?

Intuition tells me that there should be only one, but I am not sure that is correct.

Comment: Assuming *onto* $S$ then $S$ is point-wise fixed and its orthogonal complement must be in the kernel. Now note that $V=S\oplus S^{\perp}$.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by point-wise fixed? (I didn't study linear algebra in English, so I probably know the concept but not the term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by ignoring the scalar (or inner) product, and fix a subspace $S\subset V$.

All the projectors onto $S\,$ (which means that the image equals $S$) are in 1-to-1 correspondence with subspaces $K\subset V$ such that that $S\oplus K=V$. The
mutual relationship between projector and complementing subspace $K$ is determined by $K=\ker(\text{ projector })$. This holds true in every vector space $V$.

In the lucky case where a scalar product is available for $V$, a distinguished choice for the complementing subspace can be made, namely the orthogonal complement $S^\perp$. It is uniquely determined by $S$.

It follows that *there is exactly one orthogonal projector onto $S$*, thus confirming your intuition.