# General Projections

Tags: vector-spaces, projection

I have the following problem, however I cannot understand what  I exactly have to show, as I am not sure what  $x_u$ means.

So can someone tell me if it is the projection of $x$ onto $U$, or is it the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $U$?
Or is just every projection orthogonal :D ?

Problem:

> Let $U,V\subset\mathbb C^n$ be two subspaces, such that $\mathbb C^n = U+V$ and further assume $U\cap V = \{0\}$.
>
> Show that every $x\in\mathbb C^n$ can be written as $x=x_u+x_v$ with $x_u\in U$ and $x_v\in V$ and that this decomposition is unique.

Comment: There is the recent post "How many *orthogonal projectors* on a given subspace are there?", and the answer is "one". This is 
[explained there.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057906/316749)
The problem you are going to solve deals with *Direct sum decompositions*
$U\oplus V$ of $\,\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: Is then  $x_u =\ < $x , $u > $u ?

Comment: This holds for all $x$ if $U$ is 1-dimensional and $u\in U$ is a unit vector.

Comment: oh should then be $x_u =( <$x,$u>/ $u times   $u) * $u

Answer (score 2):

Technically, $x_U$ is just some vector in $U$ which, together with $x_V$ happens to make up $x$. You don't need to interpret it as anything special to do the problem.

But yes, it is a projection of $x$ onto $U$. But not necessarily orthogonal. It is the projection "along" $V$. So if $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, then yes, $x_U$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $U$, but not in general.

For instance, if $n = 2$, with $U$ being the span of $(1, 0)$ and $V$ being the span of $(1, 1)$, then the projection is *not* orthogonal. Given $x = (0, 1)$, we actually have $x_U = (-1, 0)$ and $x_V = (1, 1)$.

Comment: Is then  $x_u =\ < $x , $u > $u ?