# For an orthogonal projection $P$, how do you prove $Px=x$ is the unique orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an inner product space $\mathcal{V}$ with a subspace $\mathcal{S}$. Let $P$ be an orthogonal projection of $\mathcal{V}$ onto $\mathcal{S}$.

By the definition of orthogonal projections, a linear transformation $P$ is said to be a an orthogonal projection iff $P^2=P=P^*$. Using this, can we show that the only possible orthogonal projection is

$$Px=\begin{cases} x & \text{if $x \in \mathcal{S}$}\\
 0 & \text{if $x \notin \mathcal{S}$} 
 \end{cases}$$

Showing that $P$ is an orthogonal projection is easy, but how do I prove its uniqueness?

Comment: Well you said it. For any orthogonal projection $P$, $Px=x$ or $Px=0$. Now if there are two orthogonal projections (to $\mathcal{S}$), how would they be different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many orthogonal projectors on a given subspace are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936411/how-many-orthogonal-projectors-on-a-given-subspace-are-there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists a projection $P'$ other than $P$, then it satisfies
$P'P' = P'.$ We need to prove $P'=P$. Multiply $P$ on both side gives
$P'P=PP=P$ and $PP'=PP=P$, which means we need to prove both.

By the definition of $P$, if $x\in S$ then
$P'Px = P'x,$
$P'P'Px = P'x,$ which means $P'P=P'P'P$ on $x\in S$, multiply $P'^{-1}$ on both left sides gives $P=P'P$.
Multiply $P$ on $P=P'P$ gives
$PP=PP'P$ and this gives
$P=PP'.$ That finish the proof on $x\in S$

The proof on $x\notin S$ is similar.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to do it in a slightly different way which felt easier to me. Could you verify that I haven't missed anything?
If $x \in S$, then $PP'x=Px \implies PP'=P \implies PP'=PP \implies P=P'\;$
. If $x \notin S$, then $P'Px=Px \implies P'P=P \implies P'P=PP \implies P=P'$
. Hence, for all $x \in V$, $P=P'$

Comment: There is no evidence that $P'x=x$, you could only use that $P'P'=P'$.

Comment: Oh no. That was a poor mistake on my part. The first part: if $x \in S$ should be $P'Px=P'x \implies P'P=P' \implies P'P=P'P' \implies P'=P$

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is a subspace of an inner product space $X$, then the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $S$ is the unique $s \in S$ such that $(x-s)\perp S$. That's the orthogonal projection that you learned in Calculus. $s$ is unique if it exists because, if $(x-s)\perp S$ and $(x-s')\perp S$ for some $s,s'\in S$, then $(s-s')\perp S$, which makes $s-s'$ orthogonal to itself, and, hence, the $0$ vector. So the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $S$ is unique if it exists.

The property of an orthogonal projection $P_S$ onto $S$ is that $x\perp S \implies P_S x = 0$. But $x\notin S$ does not imply $P_Sx=0$ because there may be a non-zero component of $x$ in $S$. Using this definition you can show that
$$
            P=P^2=P^*.
$$
These properties also define an orthogonal projection onto $S=PX$.